# ios how to replace a color from the camera preview with a texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I would like to do something like this: 
Have the camera on and tap on the screen to get the color of that area and then replace that color with a texture. I have done something similar by replacing the color on the screen with another color (that is still not working right though), but replacing with a texture is more complex i think.
So please, can somebody give me a hint on how i can do this?
Also , on how to create the texture.
Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

basically you will want to do this with a boolean operation in the fragment shader.

you'll need to feed two textures to the shader, one is the camera image, the other is the replacement image. then you need a function which determines if the per-fragment color from the camera texture is within a certain color range (which you choose), and depending on that either show the camera texture or the other texture.

your question is a bit vague, you should try to break it down into smaller problems. the tricky part, if you haven't done this before, is getting the OpenGL boilerplate code right.

you need to know:

- how to write, compile and use basic GLSL shaders
- how to load images into OpenGL textures and use them in your shaders (search for sampler2d)

a good first step is to do the following:
figure out how to show a texture as a flat fullscreen image using 2D geometry. You'll need to render two triangles, and map the texture's coordinates (UV) onto the triangle points.

if you follow this tutorial you'll be able to do the thing you want:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/70208/opengl-es-pixel-shaders-tutorial